# Avro files created using Spark and having DecimalType fields

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I created Avro datafiles using spark2 and then defined a hive table pointing to the avro datafiles.

```
val trades= spark.read.option("compression","gzip").csv("file:///data/nyse_all/nyse_data").select($"_c0".as("stockticker"),$"_c1".as("tradedate").cast(IntegerType),$"_c2".as("openprice").cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(10,2)),$"_c3".as("highprice").cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(10,2)),$"_c4".as("lowprice").cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(10,2)),$"_c5".as("closeprice").cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(10,2)),$"_c6".as("volume").cast(LongType))    
trades.repartition(4,$"tradedate",$"volume").sortWithinPartitions($"tradedate".asc,$"volume".desc).write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("/user/pawinder/spark_practice/problem6/data/nyse_data_avro")

spark.sql("create external table pawinder.nyse_data_avro(stockticker string, tradedate int, openprice decimal(10,2) , highprice decimal(10,2), lowprice decimal(10,2), closeprice decimal(10,2), volume bigint) ROW FORMAT SERDE  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'  OUTPUTFORMAT  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat' location '/user/pawinder/spark_practice/problem6/data/nyse_data_avro'")
```

Querying the hive table fails with the following error:

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error
>   while processing writable
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroGenericRecordWritable@178270b2
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:172)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive
>   Runtime Error while processing writable
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroGenericRecordWritable@178270b2
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:563)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:163)
>           ... 8 more Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found string, expecting union

On some debugging I found that the datatypes that were defined as Decimal(10,2) are marked as String in the avro data files:

```
 [pawinder@gw02 ~]$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/pawinder/spark_practice/problem6/data/nyse_data_avro/part-00003-f1ca3b0a-f0b4-4aa8-bc26-ca50a0a16fe3-c000.avro |more
    Objavro.schema▒{"type":"record","name":"topLevelRecord","fields":[{"name":"stockticker","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"tradedate","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"o
    penprice","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"highprice","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"lowprice","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"closeprice","type":["string","n
    ull"]},{"name":"volume","type":["long","null"]}]}
```

I am able to query the same hive table in spark-shell. Is spark-sql DecimalType not recognised by avro serde? I am using spark 2.3.